# presto/mysql: why id from table A where id in table B != id from table B where id in table A

Tags: mysql, database, data-manipulation, presto

I am trying to compare the differences between two tables IDs. And I get different number of records when I used query A in B and query B in A. I am getting very confused. Should they return the same ID (according to the venn diagram)?

```
select *
from table_a 
where id in (select id from table_b)
```

and

```
select *
from table_b 
where id in (select id from table_a)
```

[image]

Comment: i mean should the ID count number from table A in B be the same as ID  count number from table B in A. As I am getting the intersection of IDs from table A and table B

Comment: are you ruling out duplicates?

Comment: you mean a ID can appear multiple times in table A or table B?

Comment: that is what i mean

Comment: oh, it's possible there are IDs appearing multiple times. So it the distinct ID should be the same then.